# after using \multirow, my table looks like this. How can I fix the cell so that it looks complete and centered text?

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment, multirow, cell

```latex
\begin{table}[H]
  \centering
    \caption{The summary of FFNN design parameters and inputs}
    \label{tab:ffnn_smry}
    \begin{tabular}{|ll|}
    \hline
\textbf{Network Type} & FFNN \\ \hline
\multirow{3}{*}{\textbf{Input Parameters}} & $CO_2$ concentrations ($ppm$)& \\
& Ventilation rates ($L/s$) & \\
& Class schedule \\ \hline
\textbf{Target(s)} & Number of occupants \\ \hline
\textbf{Training Algorithm} & Bayesian regularization \\ \hline
\textbf{Number of Neurons} & 15 \\ \hline
\textbf{Performance} & MSE \\ \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

Answer (score 2):

The first line had a `&` to much.

However, I suggest you add some additional packages, and make the table more readable. [array](https://ctan.org/pkg/array) give you `\extrarowheight` to add some space above the cell content, [booktabs](https://ctan.org/pkg/booktabs) to have better spacing and nicer rules, [threeparttable](https://ctan.org/pkg/threeparttable) to adjust the caption to the table width. See example 2.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{multirow}

\begin{document}



\begin{table}
  \centering
    \caption{The summary of FFNN design parameters and inputs}
    \label{tab:ffnn_smry}
    \begin{tabular}{|ll|}
    \hline
\textbf{Network Type} & FFNN \\ \hline
\multirow{3}{*}{\textbf{Input Parameters}} & $CO_2$ concentrations ($ppm$) \\
& Ventilation rates ($L/s$)  \\
& Class schedule \\ \hline
\textbf{Target(s)} & Number of occupants \\ \hline
\textbf{Training Algorithm} & Bayesian regularization \\ \hline
\textbf{Number of Neurons} & 15 \\ \hline
\textbf{Performance} & MSE \\ \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{table} 

\end{document}
```

**Example 2 - booktabs etc.**

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{array, multirow, threeparttable, booktabs}
\setlength{\extrarowheight}{1pt}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\centering
\begin{threeparttable}

\caption{The summary of FFNN design parameters and inputs\label{tab:ffnn_smry}}
\begin{tabular}{@{}>{\bfseries}ll@{}}
\toprule
 Network Type                      & FFNN                        \\ \midrule
\multirow{3}{*}{Input Parameters} & $CO_2$ concentrations ($ppm$)\\
                                  & Ventilation rates ($L/s$)    \\
                                  & Class schedule               \\
\cmidrule(l){2-2}
Target(s)                         & Number of occupants           \\ 
Training Algorithm                & Bayesian regularization       \\ 
Number of Neurons                 & 15                            \\ 
Performance                       & MSE                           \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{threeparttable}

\end{table} 

\end{document}
```

Comment: I suggest adding siunitx for the units and a chemistry dedicated package such as mhchem for typesetting the CO2, assuming that CO2 refers to carbon dioxide

Comment: @leandriis It is several packages that could be added, lmodern (or a nicer font), babel and microtype,